# CA LISA unable to create VS from Req/Rsp pairs

Tags: virtualization, ca-lisa

I have been trying to create a REST/Json Virtual service on CA LISA 7.5 (we can’t update), using request response pairs. The request response looks like the following:

> Name-req

```
GET /cods_party_web/party/111700 HTTP/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
x-abc-outlet-id: 017879
x-abc-user-id: CTM
x-abc-consent-level: 2
x-abc-application-id: 00028
x-abc-outlet-id-type: OU_ID
x-abc-user-id-type: 1
x-IBM-Client-Id: XXX....
x-IBM-Client-Secret: XXX...
```

> Name-rsp

```
HTTP/1.1 200 {"party":{"partyId":111700,"foreNames":["Julie","Pamela",""],"lastName":"Duncan","initials":["J"],"...lots of content......."type":"EMAIL"}],"associatedOU":null}
```

When I try to build the virtual service image, no matter what options I select, my VS image response is either in hex as shown below or it is blank.
 [image]

I remember having this problem 1 year ago, and was able to get the reponse to look like below but I can’t remember how I did it.

> Success response
>   [image]

Not found response.
 [image]

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not returning hex - those are just column numbers for an empty binary response.  I think the problem is your response document is not properly formed HTTP - there's no reason phrase in the status line, and you need two line feeds after the status line.  Try this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"party":{"partyId":111700,"foreNames":["Julie","Pamela",""],"lastName":"Duncan","initials":["J"],"...lots of content......."type":"EMAIL"}],"associatedOU":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you can't upgrade, so this doesn't really help you, but LISA 9.5 doesn't have this issue -- the response looks like it's supposed to.

On the other hand, CA has released a free, simpler version of LISA that also successfully generates a VS from your example.  Check it out here:

http://educationcontent.ca.com/A01/index.html